Debian Server not communicating with anything after network interface change
I have the following situation:
I have changed the network interface type of my Debian server from VMXNET3 to et1000e from VMWARE EXSI and now the server cannot communicate even with other devices on the same network.
To change the network interface type I had to shutdown the server, deleting the previous interface and create another one.
I have even tried to change again to VMXNET3 because I have discovered that the ET1000e needs the installation of its driver for Debian but it didn't work.
The strange thing is that the server acquires the IPv4 in DHCP correctly but it cannot even pint the default gateway.
I have tried to set the IP to static but nothing has changed.
Any idea on how to proceed?
The server hosts a Postgree installation and an Apache installation for an internal web server
Thanks in advice.

Why would you want the emulated e1000 over the much more efficient native vmxnet adapter in the first place?

Because my team notified me that the server is really slow from the VPN and after doing a speed test from the CLI, connected from the same network, the server has a speed of 27 mpbs in down and 12 in up. Consider that we have a 1gpbs connection and all other VMs on the same network are working with 600 mbps in down and 100 in up with no issue. Excluding the previous speed issue, I have to reestablish the connection of the server no matter what

So you are trying to get faster connection speeds by using a slower network adapter. Okay. Apart from that, you will have to update the network configuration (should be in /etc/network, /etc/netplan or /etc/NetworkManager/, depending on your Debian version) to the new device name you most probably got.

With device name you mean the network interface name? at the moment is ens192 and in the folder /etc/network there is the file interfaces and the network interface name is the same

Well, without seeing anything about your configuration it's quite impossible to help you.

What do I need to share?
